# Mobile Live Chat Agent update prechat fields doesn't work

Tags: liveagent, mobile, pre-chat, snap-ins

I couldn't update a value for the new custom prechat fields.

I am using Mobile chat-ui SDK to send a a new custom fields in `Contact` Entity. This custom field shows in CLT dashboard but didn't get the updated value that mobile client send.

Btw, we can update it manually via CLT dashboard. I verified the key in CLT setting and it's correct. 
This is mobile client code

```
    val chatConfigurationBuilder = ChatConfiguration
        .Builder(ORG_ID, BUTTON_ID, DEPLOYMENT_ID, LIVE_AGENT_POD)

    val nameData = ChatUserData("name", firstName, true)
    val keyData = ChatUserData("key__c", "key_value", true)
    val customData = ChatUserData("custom_field__c", "custom_value", true)

    val contactEntity = ChatEntity.Builder()
        .showOnCreate(true)
        .linkToTranscriptField("contact")
        .addChatEntityField(
            ChatEntityField.Builder()
                .doFind(false)
                .isExactMatch(false)
                .doCreate(true)
                .build("name", nameData)
        )
        .addChatEntityField(
            ChatEntityField.Builder()
                .doFind(true)
                .isExactMatch(true)
                .doCreate(true)
                .build("key__c", keyData)
        )
        .addChatEntityField(
            ChatEntityField.Builder()
                .doFind(false)
                .isExactMatch(false)
                .doCreate(true)
                .build("custom_field__c", customData)
        )
        .build("contact")

    chatConfigurationBuilder.apply {
        chatUserData(nameData, keyData, customData)
        chatEntities(contactEntity)
    }

    val chatConfiguration = chatConfigurationBuilder.build()
    val uiConfig = ChatUIConfiguration.Builder()
        .chatConfiguration(chatConfiguration)
        .hideQueuePosition(false)
        .disablePreChatView(true)
        .build()

    ChatUI.configure(uiConfig)
        .createClient(activity)
        .onResult { _, chatUIClient ->
            if (!ChatCore.isActive()) {
                chatUIClient.apply {
                    startChatSession(activity)
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.